# OAuth 1.0 Requests with Retrofit in Android

Tags: android, magento, oauth, retrofit, signpost

I am trying to access a Magento REST API in my Android app, using Retrofit.

What have I tried:

- SignPost and OkHttp to sign request using these classes : https://gist.github.com/f2prateek/0deb2d7ddea43e21d39b
- Custom Headers having OAuth values

But none of them have worked.

Retrofit 1.7 and OkHttp2.0RC2 don't work well with SignPost (at least the way the article suggest)

And when I downgrade for things to work, I get error `HTTP 500` Error saying `Internal Server Error`

The same credentials work using REST Client plugin for Firefox.

Is there a working solution for implementing OAuth requests with Retrofit, or any other option?

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auth 1.0 oauth\_signature creation Android for magento API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505888/auth-1-0-oauth-signature-creation-android-for-magento-api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out that the web server expected the `Accept` parameter in header, which I was missing but Firefox extension was adding.

That made the server return a 500 (sending a response telling about the error would have been wiser though)

Things are working fine now.

Thanks for giving your time!

Answer (score 4):

Give it a try to this fix *pakerfeldt's* [**signpost-retrofit**](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/signpost-retrofit) (A Retrofit extension to oauth-signpost OAuth Core 1.0a standard) !

Other fixes you can try:

- Java wrapper for retrofit [**getglue-java**](https://github.com/UweTrottmann/getglue-java).
- [**OAuthClient**](https://gist.github.com/dzolnai/9710849) by dzolnai.
- Square's [**G+ discussion**](http://is.gd/5nEoEB).
- [retrofit-oauth](https://github.com/bkiers/retrofit-oauth)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried authenticating using the magento REST api from plain java code using the scribe lib.  So far it worked for me.