# Auth 1.0 oauth_signature creation Android for magento API

Tags: android, rest, authorization, retrofit, magento-1.9

I call the Magento API with the following Autherization as header,

```
auth = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=**********************,oauth_consumer_secret=****************,oauth_token=************,oauth_token_secret=**************,oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1,oauth_timestamp=" + ConstantFunctions.GetTimeStamp() + ",oauth_nonce=" + ConstantFunctions.GetNonce() + ",oauth_signature=*******************) ;
```

While I call the API,
Getting error `oauth_problem=signature_invalid` .All other parameters validate successfully but got an error in the signature,
I try the following code to generate the signature,

```
     public static String GETHMACSHA1(String value, String key)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeyException {
        String type = "HmacSHA1";
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), type);
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(type);
        mac.init(secret);
        byte[] bytes = mac.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        return bytesToHex(bytes);
    }

    private final static char[] hexArray = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        int v;
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
```

I pass the `oauth_consumer_secret` and `oauth_token_secret` as the parameter to get signature . But its still get the same error.

How to generate the signature in android and which value I need to pass to get the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We didn't need to pass all the attribute as auth, retrofit itself handle this, we need to pass only the CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN and TOKEN_SECRET.

By following [this](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/okhttp-signpost)

**ApiUtils class will be like,**

## Kotlin

```
class ApiUtils {
companion object {
    fun getAPIService(): APIService? {
        val consumer = OkHttpOAuthConsumer(BuildConfig.CONSUMER_KEY, BuildConfig.CONSUMER_SECRET)
        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(BuildConfig.ACCESS_TOKEN, BuildConfig.TOKEN_SECRET)
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BuildConfig.BASE_URL, consumer)?.create(APIService::class.java)
    }
}
```

}

## Android Java

```
public class ApiUtils {

    private ApiUtils() {
    }

    private static final String BASE_URL = BuildConfig.BASE_URL;

    public static APIService getAPIService() {

        OkHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new OkHttpOAuthConsumer(BuildConfig.CONSUMER_KEY, BuildConfig.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(BuildConfig.ACCESS_TOKEN, BuildConfig.TOKEN_SECRET);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new SigningInterceptor(consumer))
                .build();
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL, client).create(APIService.class);
    }
}
```

and for **RetrofitClient Class**

## Kotlin

```
    class RetrofitClient {
    companion object {
        private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null
        private val gSON = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()

        fun getClient(baseUrl: String, consumer: OkHttpOAuthConsumer): Retrofit? {
            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            } else {
                logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
            }

            val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            httpClient.connectTimeout(60000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            httpClient.writeTimeout(120000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            httpClient.readTimeout(120000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            httpClient.retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            httpClient.addInterceptor(SigningInterceptor(consumer))
            httpClient.addInterceptor { chain ->
                val request = chain.request()
                val requestBuilder = request.newBuilder()
                    .header(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE_KEY, PreferenceHandler.getContentType())
                    .header(HEADER_ACCEPT_KEY, PreferenceHandler.getAcceptType())
                    .header(HEADER_CACHE_CONTROL_KEY, PreferenceHandler.getCacheControl())
                val modifiedRequest = requestBuilder.build()
                chain.proceed(modifiedRequest)
            }

            httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(logging)

            if (retrofit == null) {
                retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gSON))
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build()
            }
            return retrofit
        }

    }
}
```

## Android java

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl,OkHttpClient client) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have consumer key and consumer secret only.i used above format.Still i am getting 401 error

Comment: did you use Magento 1.9? @LavanyaVelusamy

Comment: No.I didnt use that.Can you pls help me out

Comment: ok tell me the details, such as what is your backend, and what you tried and where you got the error @LavanyaVelusamy

Comment: Backend is .net.they have given consumer key, consumer secret and have to add authorization data in Request Url.I used above method i got 401 Unauthorized access @Subin Babu

Comment: OkHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new OkHttpOAuthConsumer(AppConstants.CONSUMER_KEY, AppConstants.CONSUMER_SEC_KEY);


        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new SigningInterceptor(consumer))
                .build();

        apiCallInterface= RetrofitApiConfig.getClient(AppConstants.DASHBOARD_URL, client).create(ApiCallInterface.class);  Declared api like this                                                                                                         @GET(AppConstants.GET_SCHEDULE_LOOKUP)
    Call<Object> getScheduleLookUp();

Comment: Try this ::  https://github.com/pakerfeldt/okhttp-signpost/blob/master/src/main/java/se/akerfeldt/okhttp/signpost/OkHttpOAuthConsumer.java

Comment: @LavanyaVelusamy hello have you get the solution for this. I want to add authorization data to request body if i am passing data in header i am getting also getting error

Comment: @VishalThakkar the above solution works fine for me. Add values in OkHttpOAuthConsumer

Comment: @SubinBabu I have only consumer secret and consumer token and I have to pass authorization data in request body instead of header.

Comment: @VishalThakkar Have you found any solution if yes can you provide I have same issue with this I also have to pass request body instead of header and have no clue on it.

Answer (score 1):

For Oauth i dont think you should be passing CS and TS . You need to concatenate a set of URL-encoded attributes and parameters to construct the signature base string. please refer - 
devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/

> so in other words,  one of the params in SHA1 will be an encoded url
>   and it should be in a specific format starting with HTTP method.

[image]

the url should contains the above params before encoding.

i did a similar Oauth authentication in Woocommerce API for android please refer this gist url for more info.

https://gist.github.com/Muneefm/f4c08b2aa3accd57fa890156f74e619a

in this check the method called `getLoginUrl()` . in which i have concatenate the url.