# How to remove Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ i n retrofit 2?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2

I am working on FatSecretAPI and trying to get the recipes list.

for accessing that  need to send some parameters which are:

```
oauth_consumer_key  String  --Your API key when you registered as a developer
oauth_signature_method  String--    The method used to generate the signature (only HMAC-SHA1 is supported)
oauth_timestamp Int--   The date and time, expressed in the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT. The timestamp value must be a positive integer and must be equal or greater than the timestamp used in previous requests
oauth_nonce String  --A randomly generated string for a request that can be combined with the timestamp to produce a unique value
oauth_version   String--    MUST be "1.0"
oauth_signature String--    The signature, a consistent reproducible concatenation of the request elements into a single string. The string is used as an input in hashing or signing algorithms.
method  String  --MUST be "recipes.search"
```

And in response I will these:

```
recipe_id – the unique recipe identifier.
recipe_name – the name of the recipe.
recipe_url – URL of this recipe item on www.fatsecret.com.
recipe_description – A short description of the recipe.
recipe_image – URL of this recipe item's default image, only if this is available
```

I have a json response like this:

```
  {  
   "recipes":{  
      "recipe":{  
         "recipe_description":"Healthy fish with a tasty sauce.",
         "recipe_id":"91",
         "recipe_image":"http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/static\/recipe\/bf0c5912-9cf8-4e7a-b07a-6703c4b77082.jpg",
         "recipe_name":"Baked Lemon Snapper",
         "recipe_url":"http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/recipes\/baked-lemon-snapper\/Default.aspx"
      }
   }
}
```

And my Apicall looks like:

public interface MyCallApi {

```
String BASE_URL = "http://platform.fatsecret.com/";


@POST("rest/server.api/")
Call<Recipes> getRecipes(@Query("oauth_consumer_key") String oauth_consumer_key,
                         @Query("oauth_signature_method") String oauth_signature_method,
                         @Query("oauth_timestamp") int oauth_timestamp,
                         @Query("oauth_nonce") String oauth_nonce,
                         @Query("oauth_version") String oauth_version,
                         @Query("oauth_signature") String oauth_signature,
                         @Query("method") String method);
```

And my POJO class for recipes is like:

```
public class Recipes {
    @SerializedName("recipe")
    @Expose
    private Recipe recipe;

    public Recipe getRecipe() {
        return recipe;
    }

    public void setRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
        this.recipe = recipe;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [recipe = " + recipe + "]";
    }
}
```

And for the data inside the recipes object are:

```
public class Recipe {
    @SerializedName("recipe_name")
    @Expose
    private String recipe_name;
    @SerializedName("recipe_url")
    @Expose
    private String recipe_url;
    @SerializedName("recipe_description")
    @Expose
    private String recipe_description;
    @SerializedName("recipe_image")
    @Expose
    private String recipe_image;
    @SerializedName("recipe_id")
    @Expose
    private String recipe_id;

    public String getRecipe_name() {
        return recipe_name;
    }

    public void setRecipe_name(String recipe_name) {
        this.recipe_name = recipe_name;
    }

    public String getRecipe_url() {
        return recipe_url;
    }

    public void setRecipe_url(String recipe_url) {
        this.recipe_url = recipe_url;
    }

    public String getRecipe_description() {
        return recipe_description;
    }

    public void setRecipe_description(String recipe_description) {
        this.recipe_description = recipe_description;
    }

    public String getRecipe_image() {
        return recipe_image;
    }

    public void setRecipe_image(String recipe_image) {
        this.recipe_image = recipe_image;
    }

    public String getRecipe_id() {
        return recipe_id;
    }

    public void setRecipe_id(String recipe_id) {
        this.recipe_id = recipe_id;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [recipe_name = " + recipe_name + "," +
                " recipe_url = " + recipe_url + ", " +
                "recipe_description = " + recipe_description + "," +
                " recipe_image = " + recipe_image + "," +
                " recipe_id = " + recipe_id + "]";
    }
}
```

Retrofit implementations are:

```
public class RecipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


final static private String APP_METHOD = "GET";
final static private String APP_KEY = "here api key";
final static private String APP_SECRET = "ssecret key";
final static private String APP_URL = "http://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api";
private static final String HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM = "HMAC-SHA1";


private static String paramify(String[] params) {
    String[] p = Arrays.copyOf(params, params.length);
    Arrays.sort(p);
    return join(p, "&");
}

private static String join(String[] array, String separator) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0)
            b.append(separator);
        b.append(array[i]);
    }
    return b.toString();
}


private static String nonce() {
    Random r = new Random();
    StringBuilder n = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < r.nextInt(8) + 2; i++)
        n.append(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
    return n.toString();
}

Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
int ts = Integer.parseInt(tsLong.toString());

private static String[] generateOauthParams() {
    return new String[]{
            "oauth_consumer_key=" + APP_KEY,
            "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1",
            "oauth_timestamp=" +
                    Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() * 2).toString(),
            "oauth_nonce=" + nonce(),
            "oauth_version=1.0",
            "format=json"};
}

private static String signature(String[] params) {
    String[] p = {RecipeActivity.APP_METHOD, Uri.encode(RecipeActivity.APP_URL), Uri.encode(paramify(params))};
    String s = join(p, "&");
    SecretKey sk = new SecretKeySpec(APP_SECRET.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
    try {
        Mac m = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
        m.init(sk);
        return Uri.encode(new String(Base64.encode(m.doFinal(s.getBytes()), Base64.DEFAULT)).trim());
    } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException | java.security.InvalidKeyException e) {
        Log.w("FatSecret_TEST FAIL", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe);


    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl(MyCallApi.BASE_URL)
            .build();

    MyCallApi myCallApi = retrofit.create(MyCallApi.class);
    Call<Recipes> call = myCallApi.getRecipes("c30f50a1c5474070b4db11a506d99666",
            "HMAC-SHA1", ts
            , nonce()
            , "1.0", signature(generateOauthParams()),
            "recipes.search");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Recipes>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Recipes> call, @NonNull Response<Recipes> response) {
            Log.i("if works", response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Recipes> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Log.i("if not", t.getMessage());
        }
    });

}
```

}

*But I am getting the mostly asked error. And I am not able to solve it on my own.* I am new to retrofit. I don't know what and where I am doing wrong, kindly check the implementations and guide me to get the response successfully*. Remember I have to send those parameters along with the retrofit request.*

Comment: Did you use oAuth 1.0 ?

Comment: You might miss out on parsing json object before you are passing "recipes" inner object.

Comment: @SubinBabu In required parameters i just need to specify  oAuth version 1.0 as per their official docs.

Comment: Please check my answer on following link and need any help iwill answer to your question in detail  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49607975/6299045

Comment: @JayDangar so how to resolve that?

Comment: @SubinBabu i have a doubt that i am using parameters in a wrong way but can't figure out.

Comment: @itsandpro first parse root element and from that root element get whatever child object you want.

Comment: What exactly json from the server when you get this error?

Comment: you can using `Postman` to get the json result

Comment: @GianhTran i have posted my response from json in the question .plz take a look.

Comment: @itsandpro I worried the response is different in your case, but if you make sure about that, everything is fine with @Android Team solution, but please try this again with a notation `@Expose`

Comment: i have used @Expose notation.

Answer (score 2):

make one more pojo class like this ..

```
public class RecipeResponse{

@SerializedName("recipes")
private Recipes recipes;

public void setRecipes(Recipes recipes){
    this.recipes = recipes;
}

public Recipes getRecipes(){
    return recipes;
}
```

}

after that change api call when you used..

```
Call<RecipeResponse>
```